# What is the limit of the GPU range in this screenshot?

Tags: nsight, openscenegraph

I'm currently inspecting an execution of our software through the Nsight profiler with visual studio.

I'm wondering what is the trigger for the "start" and "stop" of the ranges for the `CPU` and `GPU GPU 0 - G...` as highlighted in the following image, more precisely, what would trigger the switch from `CPU` frame 53 to `CPU` frame 54, same for `GPU GPU 0` frame 53 to `GPU GPU 0` frame 54:

[image: nsight screenshot]

Second question: should I care?

The 'frame' range is before and after I call the 'frame' method of the viewer in OSG.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could configure nSight to interpret different events to detect start and end times of a rendering frame, but the default would be the final buffer swap or glFlush issued by OSG at the end of all rendering traversals.